# correct way of using coroutines in kotlin 1.3

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, anko

I started using corotuines when it was still in experimental. With `anko`, I had something like

```
async(UI) {
    val request = bg { sendRequest() }
    val result = request.await()
    // UI work
}
```

I really like how it is structured and it does provide cleaner code vs callback hell imo. I just realized coroutines is now in stable channel and couldn't wait to try it out. I updated my kotlin and anko and now I have this

```
doAsync {
    val result = sendRequest()
    uiThread {
        // ui work
    }
}
```

Am I doing it correctly? This structure seems ugly to me. Although it might be more readable but I still like the old way of calling `await()`. Or maybe I miss something here? I remember one of the selling points when `coroutines` was introduced is less curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Anko to get good code with coroutines. Also, you don't need `async` and in fact you should avoid it for cases like yours, where you just want to make a non-blocking call and don't want to launch several such calls concurrently. Your basic idiom should be

```
myScope.launch {
    val result = sendRequest()
    // UI work
}
```

where `sendRequest()` is

```
suspend fun sendRequest() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... body ... }
```

If you are calling this from an Android `Activity`, then `myScope` can be just the implicit `this`, and your activity must implement `CoroutineScope`:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity, CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main
    ...
}
```

To get more insights, [Explicit Concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/explicit-concurrency-67a8e8fd9b25) by Roman Elizarov is highly recommended reading.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This sounds like a good idea but I still like the old way  of using coroutines. That way I don't need to go back and modify all my request methods to suspend.

Comment: If your request method isn't suspendable, then you must wrap calling it into a `withContext`. In its basic effect this is the same as wrapping in `async` and immediately `await`ing on it, but behaves correctly in the face of failures. So in any case you should avoid `async-await`, which you should use strictly when you want to achieve concurrency (as opposed to merely avoiding blocking the UI thread).